# Using execvp,fork and wait to execute codes in file

Tags: c, fork, exec, strtok

I have been using execvp to execute unix commands written in a text file. Below is the code i have written but it doesn't seem to work.
I am reading lines from a file and each line contains a unix command(mv,cp etc).

```
#include<stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
    {   pid_t  pid;
        pid_t child_pid;
        int child_status;  
        char *token;    
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        int i,j,ctr,rc_wait;
        if( fp == NULL){
            perror("An error has occurred\n");
            exit(1);
            }
        char buff[100];
        while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)){    
            child_pid=fork();
            if(child_pid<0){
                printf("\nfork failed, error");
                exit(0);
            }
            else if(child_pid==0){
            //printf("\nString value = %s", buff);
            token = strtok(buff, " \t");
            execvp(token,buff);
            }
            else{
            rc_wait = wait(NULL);
            continue;
            }

            }   

            }
            return 0;
            }
```

input file has been provided as an argument to the program and the input contains below as example:

```
    cp temp1/f1.txt              temp2/
    mv temp1/f2.c                           temp2/
    cp temp1/f3.txt                temp2/
    cp temp1/f4.txt                temp2/
    cp temp1/f5.txt                temp2/
    cp temp1/f6.txt                 temp2/
    mv temp1/f7.c                   temp1/f8.c
    mv temp1/f9.c                   temp2/
    cp temp1/f1.txt              temp1/f1a.txt
```

Comment: And how doesnt it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing `strtok` and `execvp`. The former mutates the input string as you call it, so after it has run once, it's split up `buff` by a `NUL` (`token` and `buff` actually refer to the same address after the first call, though `token` would change after additional tokenization). You can only use `strtok` to fully parse the input if you make copies of each result as it's generated (e.g. via `strdup` if you can rely on modern POSIX standards), because only the most recently returned pointer is ever valid.

Your `execvp` usage is also wrong; the second argument to `execvp` is an array of C-style strings, `char*`s (the array itself being terminated with a `NULL` pointer). You passed it a plain array of `char` (one string, not an array of them).

Please read the `man` pages for both APIs; you're so far off the mark it's clear you're just guessing at how they work.